# Design pattern to implement Database operations

Tags: c#, database, xamarin

I am trying to implement design pattern in my project and have been reading material over net.

we have a sales application ( in C# ) where in we are storing entities like

```
Customer 
Contacts
Sales Order
Lead
Opportunity
```

This is how i am planning to implement design pattern.

`Entity` would be the base class and it has common variables

```
namespace DesignModel.Model
{
    class Entity
    {
        protected IDBOperation dbOperation;
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int isSync { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }

        public void insert()
        {
            dbOperation.insertData();

        }

        public void update()
        {
            dbOperation.updateData();
        }
        public void delete()
        {
            dbOperation.deleteData();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `Contact` class that is extending `Entity` class. `Contact` class would have its own properties too.

```
namespace DesignModel.Model
{
    class Contact : Entity
    {
        public Contact()
        {
             dbOperation = new DBOperations();

        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string jobtitle { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Now what i have derived from the nature of this application is each entity has following operations for database interaction and to fetch data from server.

for database operation

```
insert
update
delete
```

to get and send data from server

```
getData
sendData
```

based on that i have created an interface named `IDBOperation`

```
namespace DesignModel.Database
{
    interface IDBOperation<T>
    {
        void insertData(T entity) ;
        void updateData(T entity);
        void deleteData(T entity);

        void displayData();

    }
}
```

and concrete class DBOperations that implements `IDBOperation`

```
namespace DesignModel.Database
{
    class DBOperations : IDBOperation<Entity>

    {

        public void insertData(Entity e) {

            Debug.WriteLine("insertData "+e.id );

        }

        public void deleteData(Entity e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("deleteData" + e.id);

        }

        public void updateData(Entity e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("updateData" + e.id);

        }
        public void displayData()
        {

        }
    }
```

and at last `Contact` class

```
namespace DesignModel.Model
{
    class Contact : Entity
    {
        public Contact()
        {
             dbOperation = new DBOperations();

        }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string company { get; set; }
        public string jobtitle { get; set; }

    }
}
```

i am using contact as follows

```
    Contact contactData = new Contact();
    contactData.id = "1234";
    contactData.isSync = 1;
    contactData.jobtitle = "Sales Manger";
    contactData.insert(contactData);
```

I am little confused where i have been implementing it correctly or not.

the reason why i kept implementation in `DBOperation` because if new interface method comes i have to implement it at one place oppose to if i am implementing method in customer, contact and sales order classes.

one thing that worries me is `Entity` parameter in `insertData` inside `DBOperation` not sure whether i will be able to add entire contact into db or not.

so if anyone help me in providing pointers to correctly implement the design pattern in this use case then it will me more helpful

Comment: _I am trying to implement design pattern_ - and which one exactly? There are quite a few of them.

Comment: its sort of composition design pattern we can say

Comment: You don't implement a design pattern just for the sake of having implemented it or bragging but because you need to solve a particual problem. What problem are you trying to solve? Did you read somewhere about the pattern you are implementing or have you just invented it and called it a pattern?

Comment: well in my past project we havent followed any pattern due to that redundancy of code arise.  for example , to add contact in database we had insertContact , to add customer we used to have insertCustomer not if in future if any change would come in insert function then we need to modify code everywhere

Comment: @Hunt _"its sort of composition design pattern we can say "_ I can't see the [_Composite Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) blink through there.

Comment: @Hunt what you're describing sounds more like one of the principles in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Comment: i am little confused as i have just started implementing it , it would be nice if anyone could help in reviewing and suggesting few points. it could be possible that its not a composition but the idea is to remove the dependencies and creating interfaces for the same

Comment: @Hunt why not simply use an ORM like EntityFrameworks?

Comment: Does this code work? `Debug.WriteLine()` looks too sketchy and hypothetical to be reviewable.

Comment: i am using xamarin and it doesnt support EntityFramework

Comment: Xamarin does have other ORMs available, e.g. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for an **ORM**, which provides you with an intermediate layer between your application and the database for the sake of clarity.

Since you already mentioned that **EntityFramework** is not an option, you should consider developing your **own** library. It's going to take a while, but you surely won't have any headaches while hunting down the bugs of a library you didn't write or don't understand.

---

In your code, you are calling the **delete**, **insert** and **update** methods on the instances themselves, which is a bad idea per se, since these methods are executed on the database and not on that particular instance. Instead, you could solve this by refactoring your code.

I suggest you recreate the structure of your database server in your application too: you have one database server, within a server there are multiple databases (eg. abstract class for **DatabaseEntity**) and within a database there can be multiple tables (eg. abstract class for **TableEntity**). If you execute actions on a table, you might want to do this the following way:

```
public class MyServer
{
    // ....
}

public class MyDatabase : DatabaseEntity
{
    // ....
}

public class Account : TableEntity
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
}

MyServer Server = new MyServer();

Account MyAccount = Server.Database<MyDatabase>.Select<Account>(x => x.Identifier == 123);

MyAccount.Identifier = 456;
Server.Database<MyDatabase>.Update<Account>(MyAccount);

Server.Database<MyDatabase>.Insert<Account>(new Account());
```

Within that particular **Insert<>** function, you can scan through the properties and convert their names and values into an **INSERT INTO** query and execute it. You can also create an attribute for the **primary key**, which will be used as global identifier when eg. **updating** an instance. Most likely the hardest part is going to be the **Select<>** method. You literally have to examine the expression tree in the parameters, so that this expression:

```
Server.Database<MyDatabase>.Select<Account>(x => x.Identifier == 123);
```

can become pure SQL (or whatever db you're using):

```
SELECT * FROM `MyDatabase.Account` WHERE `Identifier` = 123;
```

With your **own solution**, you can shape the structure of your library to perfectly suit all your needs and to keep your code clean and well understandable.

Also, I currently have a [weekend ORM project](https://github.com/bl4y/MistyORM) on Github based on the **previously** mentioned structure, you should check out the source code. **Feel free** to adapt it to your needs or use useful snippets from it.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular dependency between model(Contact) and CRUD(IDBOperation),

```
Contact contactData = new Contact();
contactData.id = "1234";
contactData.isSync = 1;
contactData.jobtitle = "Sales Manger";
contactData.insert(contactData);
```

Stick to the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), model should not have **C**reate**R**ead**U**pdate**D**elete logic inside.
[DAO pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/data_access_object_pattern.htm) can be a way to go.

Comment: so according to you what would be the right pattern

Comment: DAO pattern can be one option. In fact you are very close just remove insert method from Contact class. Then create  DBOperations object e.g. IDBOperation db = new DBOperations(), then db.insertData(contact), hold connection towards DB in DBOperations . Hope that this helps.